Monitor multiple SQS queues altogether or individually?
I'm working on a system that uses AWS SNS/SQS as its messaging platform, which has around 100 queues, each of them having its own DLQ.
e.g.:

queue-001 / queue-001_dlq.
queue-002 / queue-002_dlq.
[...]
queue-100 / queue-100_dlq.

I would like to receive a notification when any of the DLQs receives a message (ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible >= 1).
What is the recommended approach to monitor all these queues?

Is there a way of configuring a single alarm for all these queues?
Should I just create an alarm per queue?


You'll need to create an Alarm per Queue.

@JohnRotenstein Thanks for your input. Do you know if it is common to have that many alarms?

No idea! However an alternative approach would be to schedule a Lambda function that gathers the individual metrics and creates a combined custom metric with a single Alarm. This would probably be cheaper than the individual metrics since the Alarms are 10c/month. The Lambda cost would be minimal, and possibly within your Free Tier usage.

@JohnRotenstein Your suggestion works perfectly, thanks!

An alternative approach would be to schedule a Lambda function that gathers the individual metrics and creates a combined custom metric with a single Alarm.
This would probably be cheaper than the individual metrics since the Alarms are 10c/month. The Lambda cost would be minimal, and possibly within your Free Tier usage.
